# Bootstrap Narrow marketing + Justified nav?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-tables

I'm trying to use Bootstrap's [narrow marketing example](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/marketing-narrow.html) with the [justified nav example](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/justified-nav.html).

However I've hit a bit of a problem trying to create a Dropbox using the justified nav template. Select "Downloads" from the header and the table styled is wrong I believe it's because of `display: table-cell;` but of course if you remove that it messes up.

[I've come up with this](http://jsfiddle.net/C3zUq)

Comment: Please include your code *here* in your post, not just at jsfiddle.net.

Comment: It doesn't let me says i need more reputation points or something? Why i put a link to jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
.navbar .nav li {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1%;
  float: none;
}
```

with

```
.navbar .nav > li {
   display: table-cell;
   width: 1%;
   float: none;
}
```

and each of the items of the submenu will be a line. This way, you will only apply that three rules to the direct `li` child of the `.nav` class and not to the other `li` elements.

Result: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mk8Zw/)